# django-crontab job not running on developement server

Tags: python, django, cron, django-cron, django-crontab

I have the following task in `cron.py`.

```py
from coreapp.models import Event, User

def update_survey_summary():
    print("starting")
    u = User.objects.get(email="admin@email.com")
    e = Event(
      creator=u, 
      title="Some event", 
      location="Some location",
      hosted_by="Admin"
    )
    print("saving...")
    e.save()
```

And here are crontab config in `settings.py`:

```py
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'coreapp.cron.update_survey_summary')
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django_crontab",
    ...
```

Basically, the idea is to insert a record every 5 minutes. But nothing happens, and if use `python manage.py crontab run <hash>`, the job runs successfully and indeed does insert a record in the database. What am I missing?

Comment: try python manage.py crontab add

Comment: @Akram Yes I've tried it alongside crontab -e.

Comment: @Akram I am using WSL2. You think that's the problem?

Comment: iam not mostly femiliar with django contrab. You can try celery beat for your requirement if yours didnot work, which iam mostly femiliar

Comment: By default windows does not allow background WSL tasks to run, try starting the cron service `service cron start` and see if that helps. Also note you will need to keep WSL running for cron jobs to run.